# javascript form validation not working and can't fin why

Tags: javascript, forms

So I have this html:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
<label for="FUP start date">FUP start date:</label> 
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="inputField"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="FUP end date">FUP end date:&nbsp;</label> 
<input type="text" name="inputField2" id="inputField2" />
</br>
</br>
<label for="Allowed traffic">Allowed traffic:</label>
<input type="text" name="Allowed_traffic" id="Allowed_traffic"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="Frequency">Frequency:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" name="Frequency" id="Frequency" />
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And this javascript for password (Parola):

```
<script>
function validateForm(formElement) {
  if (formElement.Allowed_traffic.length < 5) {
  alert('aaaPlease enter a password that is at least 5 characters long');
  return false;
}
if (formElement.Allowed_traffic.length > 10) {
  alert('Please enter a password that is less than 10 characters long');
  return false;
}
}

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to check on submit that the password has between 5 and 10 characters.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.length` with `.value.length`.

Comment: Technically that's not necessary, as the form submission is only cancelled if the return value is exactly false, and/or the `preventDefault` method of the event object is called. Not returning a value (returning `undefined`) allows the submission to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently looking at the `length` property of the `<input>` element itself (which probably doesn't exist). What you want to be looking at is the `length` property **of the value** of the `<input>` element, so do the following:

```
if (formElement.Allowed_traffic.value.length < 5) {
    alert('aaaPlease enter a password that is at least 5 characters long');
    return false;
}
else if (formElement.Allowed_traffic.value.length > 10) {
    alert('Please enter a password that is less than 10 characters long');
    return false;
}
```

Note that I've changed it to an `if ... else if` because if the first condition is true then the second one can't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 var Allowed_traffic = document.getElementById("Allowed_traffic");
```

instead of

```
formElement.Allowed_traffic
```

Comment: That's not really necessary, as the latter still works. The problem was with the use of `.length` instead of `.value.length`.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I guess `document.getElementById("Allowed_traffic");` is more reliable over cross browser instead of `formElement.Allowed_traffic`

Comment: That's true, and I too would prefer the first over the second for this reason, even though it's more verbose.